# AngularJs path not changing, even after apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, directive

I have a quick question about the chaning of a route trough a custom directive. I set up a menubar diretive and set up a link function. Everything in this function works correctly, but the chaning of the URL trough the `$location.path` does not. Even after using `$rootScope.apply`, it does not change.

```
define([
    '../module',
    '../namespace'
],
function (module, namespace) {
    module.directive(namespace + '.menubarDirective', function ($location,     $rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: 'true',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/app/menubar/views/menubar.html',
            scope: {},
            controller: function () {
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                $("#menubarStoreButton").click(function () {
                    $('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    $location.path('/store');
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                })

            }
        }
    });
});
```

To be clear, I use `requirejs` and $location and `$rootScope` are defined. The weird thing is, `$location.path()` before the replace gives a empty path. Also, the placement of the class 'active' works as intended.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using $timeout -

```
$("#menubarStoreButton").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $timeout(function() {
        $location.path('/store');
    });
})
```

Comment: after trying this, I get the error that $timeout is not defined.

Comment: inject $timeout in your directive , where you have injected $location

Comment: Sorry, I feel very dumb right now. I forgot to declare $timeout as a parameter. now it works as intended!

Comment: @pD7: how does timeout solves issue and are there any other ways to implement the same? using timeout is not CPU intensive?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if your path is already `/store` and you want to reload your page try navigate try `$window.location.href = "/store";`
ref: [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) and [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Comment: Thank you very much for an alternative!