# Not able to change path using $location service even after using $scope.apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I am wondering why I am not able to change my view using location service even after I use -

```
$scope.$appy() or $scope.apply;
```

I did research before posting my question. I got results of similar questions and none of those are matching my scenario.

I do not want to use timer function for achieving the same like specified in link because its CPU intensive: 
[angularjs path not changing even after apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447009/angularjs-path-not-changing-even-after-apply)

The strange behavior in my app is I am able to change location with following code in other scripts:

```
$location.path("authenticate").replace();
$scope.$apply();
```

OR

```
$location.path("authenticate").replace();
$scope.apply;
```

Which works fine without any issues.

The only difference is: Above code works fine when it gets executed without any event trigger but it takes to blank page if I use above code on button click event like this:

```
 <li data-ng-click="logout()"><a data-ng-href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
```

Any help will be helpful.

Comment: you need to add  forward slash to your path ´$location.path("/authenticate")´

Comment: I have tried that already, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying execute your code after some async execution (when logout happens, etc) - your Angular engine might not know on operation completion.

Use scope.apply with concrete action inside. Also be aware of digest process, this can fire exception

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   if(!$scope.$$phase) {
       $location.path('authenticate');
   } 
});
```

Comment: I wish it would work but giving following error:
 [INFO:CONSOLE(118)] "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Comment: Seems you need also additional check that rootScope is not in digest phase `!$rootScope.$$phase`. Before you need to inject it as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the call within the $scope.apply() like so:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $location.path('authenticate');
});
```

Comment: Gives error :
"TypeError: $scope.apply is not a function"

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part should be $scope.$apply(function(){})

Comment: What is the difference? I did not see any change in definition of function.

Comment: I updated my answer with the correction as well.

The difference was that I instead of `$scope.apply....` it should be `$scope.$apply...`